# Converting a mysql2 type to an array and sorting it in ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a query in my ruby file :

```
@mastertest = connection.execute("select code_ver,date from mastertest")
```

And I print the result of the query as below:

```
@mastertest.each do |row|
  puts row[0] : row[1]
end
```

This will print all the `code_ver` and 'date' which looks like this

```
2.0 : 2012/12/10
3.1 : 2012/11/03
2.5 : 2012/07/08
1.8 : 2012/12/11
2.5 : 2012/03/01
```

Now I want to sort this array based on my `code_ver`, but the problem is ruby does not consider this as an array, it says it is some mysql2 type.

How do I proceed further? I want to either convert this thing to 2-d array or I would want to sort it based on the `row[0]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're getting a MySQL result set object in `@mastertest` and a result set is not an array.

If you're using `mysql2`, then you should have a [`Mysql2::Result`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/Mysql2/Result) and that's `Enumerable` so it has a [`to_a`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a) method:

```
@mastertest.to_a.sort { ... }
```

If you're using the `mysql` gem, then you should have a [`Mysql::Result`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql/Mysql/Result) and you'll have to convert `@mastertest` to an Array by hand:

```
a = [ ]
@mastertest.each { |r| a.push(...) }
a.sort { ... }
```

Or you could simply let the database do the sorting:

```
@mastertest = connection.execute('select code_ver, date from mastertest order by code_ver')
```

Comment: hey I would like to use the second approach where I create an array by hand. Can you help me with the syntax of the conversion.

Comment: Or even in the first approach, when I do something like **@mastertest.to_a.sort { ... }** . What should be inside the brackets if I want to sort on my row[0] or code_ver in my query.

Comment: @sagarvikani: I'm not sure what you want your array to look like so I don't know what the "by hand" approach would look like. Try the `@mastertest.to_a` version in the console and you'll see what the array looks like, then you can fill in the `sort` block (or maybe even use `sort_by`).

Comment: I basically want a 2-D array which should be something like this 

**temp = [{code_ver, date}, {coder_ver, date} , ...... ]**

Comment: Then you could `a.push([r[0], r[1])` or maybe `a.push({ :code_ver => r[0], :date => r[1] })`.